# Xcode 6 @IBInspectable: Initialize to starting value?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

When you add @IBInspectable properties, they are initialized to essentially... nothing.

[image]

Is there a way to have these properties default to something? Say a red color for the track color, grey color for the background color and 10.0 for padding? I've tried `@IBInspectable public var padding: CGFloat = 10.0` but the "10" does not get reflected in IB.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    if self.padding == 0 {
        self.padding = 10}

}
```

source http://justabeech.com/?